# Help with this one line derivation of manipulating integrals

Tags: linear-algebra, integration

I was reading a paper and the authors stated a step of manipulating integrals that was far from obvious to me:

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_a^\infty (F_Y(z)-F_X(z))dz \\
&= e^{a/s}\int_a^\infty (F_Y(z)-F_X(z))e^{-z/s}dz + \int_a^\infty\left(\frac{e^{c/s}}{s}\int_c^\infty (F_Y(z)-F_X(z))e^{-z/s}dz\right)dc
\end{align}
$$

Some observations:

1. I think the additional $e^{-z/s}$ is the result of some change of variables in integration.
2. The integral in the first part and the inner integral in the second part is the same expression.

With those observations, I still could not derive it after several hours of attempt. I would really appreciate it if anyone knows what is going on.

---

Update: My hunch is the exact properties of the functions involved do not matter for this step. But in case they do, $F_Y$ and $F_X$ are CDFs of two distinct and bounded random variables with $\max[X] > \max[Y]$. $s$ is some large positive number such that
$$ \int_a^\infty (F_Y(z)-F_X(z))e^{-z/s}dz \geq 0$$
for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Also, I don't know how to make the fractions bigger than they are now---please let me know how I can do that or ask me to clarify if you cannot see them clearly.

Comment: Try wrapping an expression with `\large{...}` or `\Large{...}`. Compare:$$x^{y^z} \quad \large{x^{y^z}} \quad \Large{x^{y^z}}$$Or write simple fractional exponents in linear form `a/b` vs `\frac{a}{b}`

Comment: Do you have a source for the paper, or can you give a better description of the functions involved here?

Comment: @user170231 Thanks for the suggestions. The edited post addresses both issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $f(z)=F_Y(z)-F_X(z)$ and $s=1$ the formula is
$$\tag{1}
\int_a^{+\infty}f(z)\,dz=\int_a^{+\infty}f(z)\,e^{a-z}\,dz+\int_a^{+\infty}e^c\int_c^{+\infty}f(z)\,e^{-z}\,dz\,dc\,.
$$
This follows essentially from Fubini:
\begin{align}
&\int_a^{+\infty}\int_c^{+\infty}f(z)\,e^{c-z}\,dz\,dc=\int_a^{+\infty}\int_a^z f(z)\,e^{c-z}\,dc\,dz\tag{2}\\
&=\int_a^{+\infty}f(z)\,e^{-z}(e^{z}-e^{a})\,dz\tag{3}\\
&=\int_a^{+\infty}f(z)(1-e^{a-z})\,dz\,.\tag{4}
\end{align}
For any $s\not=0$ their formula is
$$\tag{1s}
\int_a^{+\infty}f(z)\,dz=\int_a^{+\infty}f(z)\,e^{\frac{a-z}{s}}\,dz+\frac{1}{s}\int_a^{+\infty}\int_c^{+\infty}f(z)\,e^{\frac{c-z}{s}}\,dz\,dc\,.
$$
Again by Fubini, the double integral here is
\begin{align}
&\int_a^{+\infty}\int_c^{+\infty}f(z)\,e^{\frac{c-z}{s}}\,dz\,dc
=\int_a^{+\infty}\int_a^zf(z)\,e^{\frac{c-z}{s}}\,dc\,dz\tag{5}\\
&=\int_a^{+\infty}f(z)\,e^{-z/s}\,s\,(e^{z/s}-e^{a/s})\,dz\tag{6}\\
&=s\int_a^{+\infty}f(z)(1-e^{\frac{a-z}{s}})\,dz\,.\tag{7}
\end{align}
This shows (1s).

Comment: This is extremely well explained. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome.